# Redis connectionstring in docker-compose

Tags: docker, redis

I have a redis running container in docker started from docker-compose.

From starting the asp.net core project from Visual Studio the redis works great with the connectionstring: `localhost:6379,defaultDatabase=0;`

but if this application is started from docker, too, the Redis cannot be connected.

if the connectionstring is: Redis:6379,defaultDatabase=0; OR localhost:6379,defaultDatabase=0; the error is: `Keyword 'defaultDatabase' requires an integer value; the value '0;' is not recognised. (Parameter 'defaultDatabase')`

if the connectionstring is: Redis:6379; OR localhost:6379 the error is: `No endpoints specified (Parameter 'configuration')`

Comment: It is difficult to help with the issue without seeing your docker-compose file and how you are setting up redis and your asp.net project. Please provide a minimum reproducible example of the docker-compose file.

Comment: Is the docker hostname for your redis container actually, "Redis"? Or is it "redis"?

Comment: Please post you docker-compose.yml

Comment: Also, the semicolon isn't required specifically for the connection string.  That's what it's complaining about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the ';' from the end of the connection string.

The error is:

```
"value '0;' is not recognised"

Keyword 'defaultDatabase' requires an integer value; the value '0;' is not recognised.
```